# Hide the url bar on a pop up window

Tags: javascript

When I use `window.open()` to do a pop up on a new window, I'm unable to hide the url bar. It still shows the url bar even though it's read only. Can I hide it? I do not want user to see the url.

Comment: Because of this limitation (see accepted answer for reason), it has been common to implements popup windows as some kind of floating `<div>` instead of actual window (many javascript libraries available out there to help with this). If you need a separate html page in the popup, you can use `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In Internet Explorer 7 and later, you cannot remove the address bar in Internet Zone windows, for security (anti-spoofing) reasons.

— http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that in other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) also so even if you **could** do it in IE, it would have been pointless. Won't it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot no longer hide the address bar in IE7. 
Read more about here in this MS article
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/community/columns/securityupgrade.mspx

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in IE7, but **only** because I have the site added to the "Trusted sites" list.

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 
        'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=300,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```

Comment: Yes, as other answers have already explained, the security limitation doesn't apply to trusted sites.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the user's security settings. if the site is in the 'local intranet' zone then you will be able to hide the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this...

```
window.open("about:blank", "popWin", "location=no");
```

But of course, the user will always be able to configure the browser to dis-allow this.  And I think by default, it will not allow it.  IF you are on their "Trusted Sites" list, this will work though.

[Read More](http://javascript.about.com/library/blpopup10.htm)