# Popup window, how to Hide URL bar in IE8

Tags: asp.net, javascript, url, popup

when I open popup window and set location=0 or location=no, url bar is still shown in IE8 and readonly.

How can hide it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot be done, modern browser don't allow it at that would be a major security flaw.
See also [this answer, shamelessly copied from David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164899/ie7-popup-hide-the-url-bar/1164921#1164921):

> In Internet Explorer 7 and later, you cannot remove the address bar in Internet Zone windows, for security (anti-spoofing) reasons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: For me if i run the code on my local environment it shides the location bar.. but when i run it on my TEST server or Prod it shows up, but is readonly.

The Strange part is that how is is hidden in my Local Environment where as its visible in the other environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)  instead of  pupup window.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide address bar. Check the [article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/HTML/Q_24763795.html).

Also check the link below.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/402ecb05-9833-4ca1-83f1-f486056a1c04