# How to use a "_self" and without toolbar, menubar, etc. in a browser using window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

What is the proper way to hide the toolbar, menubar, etc. in a browser using a window.open with _self parameter? I'm doing a online examination and I want to hide the refresh button in a browser and I think window.open is the only solution for that. Here's my code:

```
window.open("link_here", "_self", "toolbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes" );
```

The _self is working but the toolbar and another features was there. Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you even do that anymore? I think you can merely set the width/height these days.

Comment: even the width/height are not working. :(

Comment: Because of security standard; this may not be possible now. Look at below urls for more details

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243377/hiding-address-bar-in-popup-window
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673003/popup-window-how-to-hide-url-bar-in-ie8